# How to get the event Key Id and Value in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a public site in LWC, which has input Fields.

In that i have search input field, this will fetch the `Name` from custom object( Basically I'm trying to achieve to do a custom look up).

Value is displaying below to the Input field based on the text which i  entered, But When i select the any one of the result value It print's `undefined`.

On select the value, want to get the `Id` and display the `Name` in the field, Also want to clear the result set.

Below is my code, Can anyone Please guide me on this. Thanks in Advance.

**JS:**

```js
 handleselectSchool(event) {
    alert("in");
    alert(event.detail);
    alert(event.currentTarget.dataset.Id);
    alert(event.currentTarget.dataset.name);
    // alert(event.currentTarget.dataset.Id);
    // alert(event.target.dataset.menuItemId); 
  }
```

```html
<div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
        <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleKeyChangeGetSchool}
            class="slds-m-bottom_small" value={schoolVal} label="School">
        </lightning-input>
        <template if:true={schoolData}>
            <template for:each={schoolData} for:item="sc" for:index="index">
                <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item" key={sc.Id}
                    data-id={sc.Id} data-name={sc.Name}>

                    <a class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
                        onclick={handleselectSchool} aria-current="true">
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:education"
                            alternative-text="skill" title="Account"
                            size="x-small">
                        </lightning-icon>
                        &nbsp; {sc.Name}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </template>
            <!-- <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={schoolData}
                    columns={schoolcolumns} hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    show-row-number-column="false">
                </lightning-datatable> -->
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put the attributes on the link itself:

```
<a class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
    data-id={sc.Id} data-name={sc.Name}
    onclick={handleselectSchool} aria-current="true">
```